# JavaScript form DOM traversal - where is the label text?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the source HTML:

```
   <li class="box">
       <label for="text0">Career Objectives:</label>
       <div>
           <textarea id="text0" 
                     name="text0" 
                     cols="55" 
                     rows="6">
           </textarea>
       </div>
   </li>
```

Here is the traversal code that I have tried:

```
console.log($("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.nodeName);
console.log($("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.nodeType);
console.log($("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.nodeValue);
console.log($("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.innerText);
console.log($("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.innerHTML);
console.log($("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.value);
```

Here is the output:

```
#text     projectJS.js:84
3         projectJS.js:85

          projectJS.js:86 <--- 2 lines of blank output
undefined projectJS.js:87
undefined projectJS.js:88
undefined projectJS.js:89
```

As I understand the DOM:

- The parentNode is the div
- The previousSibling is the label
- The NodeType is text

What am I missing please? Where is the actual text?

EDIT this is not JQuery:

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The previousSibling is the label

No, as the the node type and name already indicate, the previous sibling is the next node between the `label` and the `div`, containing all the whitespace characters (line break after `</label>` and a couple of spaces before `<div>`).
That's also the reason for `.innerHTML`, `.innerText` and `.value` outputting `undefined`, text nodes don't have such properties.

`$("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling` would be the label.

For the label, the `nodeName` would be `label` (same as `tagName`) and the `nodeType` would be `1`, an element node.

> Where is the actual text?

The label text is the first child node (a text node) of the `label` element. You can get with:

```
$("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

or

```
$("text0").parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML
```

Depending on which libraries you have at your disposal, selecting or traversing to the label element can be simplified.

Comment: How can `$("text0")` match anything? It will try to match a tag right?

Comment: When `$` calls `document.getElementById` with the passed argument. This is not jQuery.

Comment: IE may not include the whitespace node in the DOM, in which case the `previousSibling` would indeed be the label. Suggest using something like `parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0]` to cope with the inconsistency - or, as mentioned, libraries that hide this pain.

Comment: @Felix Kling You nailed the solution and thank you for the excellent explanation

Comment: Also in modern browsers you can do `document.querySelector('label[for=text0]')`, and use `textContent` to avoid having to read the `firstChild.nodeValue` (or cope with unwanted markup in `innerHTML`).

Comment: @bobince Great addition - worked for me like this `.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML` Will also consider your second recommendation, thanks